# If $X$, $Y$ are i.i.d and mutually exclusive, then is $\Pr(\min(X,Y)=n)=\Pr(X=n)+\Pr(Y=n)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering if $X$, $Y$ are independent and mutually exclusive, then is $\Pr(\min(X,Y)=n)=\Pr(X=n)+\Pr(Y=n)$?

$\Pr(\min(X,Y)=n)=\Pr(X=n \text{ or }Y=n)=\Pr(X=n)+\Pr(Y=n)$. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You might be confusing a random variable and an event

Comment: What I mean is X=n and Y=n are mutually exclusive events

Comment: It's **not** generally true that $$\color{red}{\Pr(\min(X,Y)=n)=\Pr(X=n\text{ or } Y=n)}.$$ You maybe be thinking that $\min(X,Y)=n$ if and only if $X=n$ or $Y=n$, but this is not the case (if it were the case though, the above equation would be correct).

Comment: Then they cannot be iid.

Comment: $min(X,Y)=n$ requires one of them $=n$ and the other $\ge n$.

Comment: @kimchilover actually they can if P(X = n) = 0 and P(Y = n) = 0. And this is the only case when events are independent and mutually exclusive. Thus, technically the statement is correct as P(min(X, Y) = n) = 0 and P(X = n) + P(Y = n) = 0 + 0 = 0

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are events and "$A$ implies $B$" (i.e. $A\subseteq B$), then you cannot generally say $\Pr(A)= \Pr(B)$. But you can say $\Pr(A)\le \Pr(B)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$Pr(min(X,Y)=n)=Pr(X=n\cap Y=n)+Pr(X=n\cap Y\gt n)+Pr(Y=n\cap X\gt n)\ ,$$ since these events are mutually exclusive.

Using independence $Pr(min(X,Y)=n)=Pr(X=n)Pr(Y=n)+Pr(X=n)Pr(Y\gt n)+Pr(Y=n)Pr(X\gt n)$.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is the following:
$$P(\min(X,Y)\geq n) = P(X\geq n, Y\geq n) = P(X\geq n)P(Y\geq n) = (1-F_X(n))(1-F_Y(n))$$
$$ = 1-F_X(n)-F_Y(n)+F_X(n)F_Y(n)$$
where $F_X$ is the cdf of $X.$
Then  you have that,
$$P(\min(X,Y) = n) = P(\min(X,Y)\geq n) - P(\min(X,Y)\geq n+1)$$
$$ = F_X(n+1)-F_X(n)+F_Y(n+1)-F_Y(n)+F_X(n)F_Y(n) - F_X(n+1)F_Y(n+1).$$